# Getting Reference to StructureMap Container

Tags: structuremap, structuremap3

I'm new to StructureMap and have a scenario where I would like to get a handle to the container.

I am building a Web API service initializing StructureMap container in Application_Start of Global.asax

```
IContainer container = IoC.Initialize();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MyDependencyResolver(container);
```

But want to access container within my controllers to get instances to objects in the container.

I know I can call container.GetInstance and specify the type to get, but since I am not using ObjectFactory and initialized the container in Global.asax, I don't know a way to access it within my controllers.

What is the best way of passing the reference to container from Global.asax to rest of the application code?

Thanks,
Jay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `IContainer` dependendy in the controller's constructor.

```
public class MyController : IController
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public MyController(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Execute(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var someType = this.container.GetInstance<ISomeType>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! it was that simple, now how do I mark this as the answer :)

Comment: @Jay I don't know, have never asked a question in SO